# how to create installable customized Debian Linux?

Tags: debian

how to create installable customized Debian Linux ? i want make a installable iso from my customized Debian (my favorite settings and packages) that it has default Debian installer. (No Live CD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read answer about **preseed** in the below link:

[How to create a customized distribution based on Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71959/how-to-create-a-customized-distribution-based-on-debian)